# JBoss / Eclipse RCP Integration

Tags: jboss, jakarta-ee, eclipse-rcp

I've run into a problem with RCP and JBoss. I'm attempting to seperate the JBoss client libraries (i.e. the .jar files in the 'client' directory of the jboss distribution) from the ejbmodule. The dependency hierarchy goes:

> company.client (ejbmodule containing `ServiceRemote` bean)
>   org.jboss.client (jboss client libraries)

The problem is that when the org.jboss.client attempts to load `ServiceRemote` from the server, it tries to do a lookup on `ServiceRemote`, it can't see it, and throws a `ClassNotFoundException`

Are there any resources/best practices out there of how to do jboss integration in RCP?

Comment: Are you asking how to fix the ClassNotFoundException, or how something more general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - you can use the Eclipse Buddy system to allow low-level plugins to lookup classes which they couldn't normally see. More info here:

http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/eclipse-vms/